# Monopoly moving wrong token

Tags: monopoly

What needs to happen if you move the wrong token in monopoly? E.g. you should move 4 with your token but you take someone else's token and move it 4.

Comment: You move it back and then move the right token instead. At what point was the mistake noticed?

Comment: Noticed before the next turn.

Answer (score 2):

Undo before the next move has been made.

Comment: Alternatively play it cool and carry on. Hope for the best that the game ends soon